# Download file from DropBox via telnet on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, download, dropbox, telnet

Is it possible to download a text (or even an exe) file from Dropbox, using telnet at the command prompt on Windows XP?

If so, what are the detailed step by step commands to achieve this?

Comment: He chose a path of pain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On any Windows PC since Windows 2000, with telnet pre-installed...

```
 1. Open a CMD prompt.
 2. telnet -f GotHttpDataWithTelnet.txt
 3. open base.google.com 80
 4. GET /base/products.txt HTTP/1.0
 5. {press {enter}}
 6. {press {enter} again}
 7. {Press any key to continue...}
 8. {press {Q} then {enter} to quit Telnet}
```

If you examine the contents of the file `GotHttpDataWithTelnet.txt` you should find it contains the downloaded text data from the file http://base.google.com/base/products.txt

Thus you can see that there is a way to use telnet to download http text data from a dropbox file.

Whilst logging, telnet tacks 12 lines of junk onto the front of the log file, so you might need to strip this off manually using notepad, then rename the file to whatever you like (e.g. `bootstrap.cmd`).

You would need to customize lines 3 and 4.

Here is another example where I hypothetically use telnet to download data from dropbox:

```
 1. Open a CMD prompt.
 2. telnet -f GotHttpDataWithTelnet.txt
 3. open dl.dropbox.com 80
 4. GET /u/12345678/textfile.txt HTTP/1.0
 5. {press {enter}}
 6. {press {enter} again}
 7. {Press any key to continue...}
 8. {press {Q} then {enter} to quit Telnet}
```

However, for this example to work, you would need to replace the dropbox member number of `12345678` with your real dropbox member number, and `textfile.txt` with the actual name of the textfile you stored in the public folder in your dropbox account.

This is working for me, I thought it might be nice to share this knowledge.

Comment: Would be interesting if it worked.  But it doesnt.

Comment: telnet -f dl.dropbox.com 80, then it boots me out.

Comment: The `telnet -f TelNetLogFileName.txt` needs to be issued at the cmd prompt. (See telnet /?) for help.  The commands 3-8 are issued inside telnet at the telnet prompt. `open dl.dropbox.com 80` is a telnet command, not a cmd command.  It is different to one's usual method of calling telnet, where one follows `telnet` with the url.

Comment: You can actually cut and paste my commands straight from the second example; you only have to customize the dropbox member number.

Comment: Maybe it is neater if you combine lines 1. and 2. like this:
`telnet -f TelnetLog.txt dl.dropbox.com 80`

Comment: im doing exactly what you are typing.  after "opening" dl.dropbox.80 it drops the connection.  it does put a partial http stream into the text file tho...  in your answer you said it was "hypothetical."  did you actually do this with dropbox?

Comment: yes, the base.google.com example works verbatim, and you can use a normal web browser to compare your results.  I also use this regularly to download a file from my dropbox, but am not giving out my dropbox member number.

Comment: there's no need to be snide, a simple comment on my answer would've been sufficient. Also, it's *encouraged* to share your answer.

Comment: Much appreciated. :)